# gatling Feeder creation from list

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I am newbie to both gatling and scala .
I have a list where I am keeping track of setupValues . I want to iterate over that list later to test get Operations . How can I do that.

I basically want feeder to repeat continuously for given data in list.

I tried creating feeder in below way below way . but its throwing exception

```
      val setupDeleteExtensions = List.empty[String]

     // I populated some values to setupDeleteExtensions List 



      val extensionIds = Iterator.continually(for (extensionId<-extmgrChain.setupInstallExtensions) yield {
        Map("extensionId" -> extensionId)
      })

    val extMgrScenerio = scenario("extensionMgr - Scenario")
        .during(Configuration.duration) {
          exitBlockOnFail(
            group("load-test") {
              exec(
                pace(Configuration.paceFrom, Configuration.paceTo),
                feed(extensionIds)
                  randomSwitch(                
                  50.00 -> group("get and Acknowledge") {
                    exec(
                      extmgrChain.getExtension(),
                      extmgrChain.getAcknowledgement()
                    )
                  },
                  50.00 -> extmgrChain.getResource(),                  
                )
              )
            }
          )
        }

exception : 
 found   : Iterator[List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]]
 required: io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederBuilder
    (which expands to)  () => Iterator[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]]
```

Can some one please help on how to create a feeder from list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have

```
val extensionIds = Iterator.continually(for (extensionId<-extmgrChain.setupInstallExtensions) yield {
    Map("extensionId" -> extensionId)
})
```

each time you .feed and get the next value from the iterator it will run the for loop across your setupInstallExtensions - this will return a List of Maps whereas gatling requires just a Map like

```
val extensionIds = extmgrChain.setupInstallExtensions.map(id => Map("extensionId" -> id)).iterator
```